# How can you have next line or auto next line in Math.tex in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, latex

I am using flutter_math_fork package to display equations. But sometimes I want to display some text after equation like,
`Math.tex('x=y \\text{Equation 1 is looooooooong}')`. I am trying to have next line as the "text is long", but `\n` doesn't work, or how can I have auto next line? Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65038810/flutter-how-to-wrap-mathematical-equations-in-a-container
You can get the solution here